# Yugabyte :: ysqlsh: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: yugabytedb

When I run the container, it gets started, it does ✅ System checks and also prints the message "Yugabyted started successfully" And then when it tries to create the sample DB, it prints this error message. Anybody has any idea on this?

ysqlsh: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

**Docker File**

FROM yugabytedb/yugabyte:latest
EXPOSE 7000 9000 5433 9042
COPY  startup_sh.sh /bin/
WORKDIR /home
RUN chmod +x /bin/startup_sh.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/startup_sh.sh"]

**startup_sh.sh is here**
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd /bin/
yugabyted start
cd /home/yugabyte/bin/
ysqlsh -c 'CREATE DATABASE yb_demo;'
ysqlsh -d yugabyte;

Comment: can you update with the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the yugabyted start takes a while to get it started and when you try to run an exec command before that service is up, you get this error. You need to wait at least 10s for the service to be up. YB confirmed this as well